# Stop re-rendering while using useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useContext which is re-rendering everything unexpectedly. You can see the results in the attached picture. My `count` updates multiples times in a second

```
**//app component**

import React, { useState, useContext, memo } from "react";
import StateProvider from "./Components/StateComp";
import Count from "./Components/Count";
import CountUpdater from "./Components/CountUpdater";
const App = memo(() => {
  return (
    <>
      <StateProvider>
        <Count/>
        <CountUpdater />
      </StateProvider>
    </>
  );
})
export default App;


**//StateProvider comp**

import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
export const StateContext = createContext();
function StateProvider({children}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1000);
  return <StateContext.Provider value={{count, setCount}}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>;
}
export default StateProvider;


**//Count Comp**

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { StateContext } from "./StateComp";
function CountComp() {
  const { count } = useContext(StateContext);
  return <h1>Count: {count}</h1>;
}
export default CountComp;


**//CountUpdater comp**

import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { StateContext } from "./StateComp";
function CountUpdater() {
  const { count, setCount } = useContext(StateContext);
  setInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("Updated count: ", count);
  }, 1000);
  return <h1>Updated count: {count}</h1>;
}
export default CountUpdater;
```

How can I resolve this, memo isn't working and I tried useEffect adding dependencies but its too worthless?

Console Results:

[image: Console Results]

Comment: I can't see any console logs in the code you provided.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `memo()` in the __App__ component ?

Comment: amm currently not @MichaelRovinsky I was trying other things

Comment: where you used your console?

Comment: Hey @Keith, thanks for looking into. I removed it later but I don't think its affecting anything

Comment: Alright, I have added the console logs again

Comment: Your setInterval wants to be in a useEffect, and don't forget clearInterval on the dismount (return function of useEffect), your basically generating a new setInterval every second, and these end up stacking up.

Comment: Oh awsum! thanks @Keith it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear out your timeout inside useEffect.

```
function CountUpdater() {
    const { count, setCount } = useContext(StateContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCount(count + 1);
            console.count('updated');
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [count, setCount]);

    return <h1>Updated count: {count}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks @Sifat this was exactly the same I was writing

Comment: upss, yeah i just saw that. There is no restriction in upvoting it though ;)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @keith, I found out its answer. Like he said, I needed to put `clearInterval` on return() also in useEffect

```
**//CountUpdater comp**

function CountUpdater() {
  const { count, setCount} = useContext(StateContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval= setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count+ 1);
      console.log("Updated Count: ", count);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count, setCount]);
  
  return <h1>Updated count: {count}</h1>;
}

export default CountUpdater;
```

Comment: This will work, but because count is the effect and not the dependency, you can pass `[]`, otherwise what you will find is that your creating/destroying a new setInterval every second,, and in that case you could just as well used `setTimeout` instead.